# Mode prioritising minimum or maximum

Tags: r

I'm wanting to calculate a mode value for my dataset (split by other factors, so each group has its own mode value, which I'll probably be doing using dplyr if that makes a difference).  I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) that discusses a function for locating *a* modal value.

The thing is, the code pointed to above simply returns the *first* modal value, so what value is returned varies depending on the order of the dataset.  I instead want to create two functions, focussing on the highest and lowest modes in multi-modal distributions.

For example, in the vector

```
x <- c(4.0, 1.0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 4.0, 0.3, 4.0)
```

I would want `minmode(x)` to return `2.2`, and `maxmode(x)` to return `4.0`.  Can anyone explain to me how to adapt the code linked above (or create a new function) to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach in base R by modifying the code you linked to (digEmAll's suggestion on the accepted answer):

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
```

This will return all the modes, which you could then use for minmode(x) or maxmode(x):

```
x <- c(4.0, 1.0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 4.0, 0.3, 4.0)
min(Mode(x))
# [1] 2.2
max(Mode(x))
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the `range` of the most frequent value. Using a *tidy* approach, I would tackle this way.

```
library(dplyr)

mode_range <- function(df, x) {

  require(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)

  var <- quo(x)

  val <- df %>%
    group_by(!!var) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    filter(n == max(n)) %>%
    select(!!var) %>%
    unlist

  range(val)

}

df <- tibble(x = c(4.0, 1.0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 4.0, 0.3, 4.0))

mode_range(df, x)[1] # min value
# [1] 2.2

mode_range(df, x)[2] # max value
# [1] 4
```

Comment: I am not strictly after the range.  My final result is I am creating a table with the count, mean value, trimmed mean value, median value, low mode value, high mode value, etc for each group - I think it will be easier for them to be added to the table if they're separate calls rather than one call that I then have to split out somehow...